# How to add style for combination of elements nth child?

Tags: html, css, sass, less, scss-mixins

This is related to calendar styling. When we select date range in the calendar, has to highlight first and last date in dark green and in between dates should be highlighted in light green. But it's not possible to select first and last element using nth-child

```
.p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-datepicker-calendar tr td>span.p-highlight {
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
.p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-datepicker-calendar tr td>span.p-highlight:first-child,
.p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-datepicker-calendar tr td>span.p-highlight:last-child {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score -1):

instead of using `:first-child` and `:last-child` you can use `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type`, this selector select your target as first and last element that is in your container

your can use this little js code for add these classes for first and last child elements in your code:

```
const highlights = document.querySelectorAll('.p-calendar .p-datepicker .p-datepicker-calendar tr td>span.p-highlight');
highlights[0].classList.add('first-date');
highlights[highlights.length - 1].classList.add('last-date');
```

i wish this work for ya

Comment: sorry it's not working

Comment: can i see your html code?

Comment: I can't share it, but without nth-child the lightgreen background color working. But has to differential with first and last date

Comment: im sorry man , so it might because your span.p-highlight  not exactly in your td tags , i hope above js code help you buddy